# not all of references have bib what should i do?

Tags: bibtex

I have some papers that I could not find their .bib , but how can I do in a way that if I have written some of them by hand , the rest could be written using the .bib files

how is it possible ?

I have these parts in my code :

```
\cleardoublepage
% ---- Bibliography ----
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografia}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibl_tesi}
%\nocite{*}
```

and

```
\renewcommand\bibname{references}
```

and I can not open the first one that apears in my list bibl_tesi

Comment: Why not just write the bib?

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what you're asking. How can you do what? What do you mean 'I could not find their .bib'? Typically, the `.bib` file is something you write. It has the contents you specify.

Comment: @cfr There are many databases that'll export BibTeX format, as I'm sure you know – OP presumably can't find one pre-made.

Comment: @SeanAllred Yes, I know that. But I still don't understand the question. Do what? Or what's been written by hand? The `.bib` files?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to have some references prepared by hand (in a hand-coded `thebibliography` environment) and the rest generated from a `.bib` file using either `bibtex` or `biblatex` (you tagged your question `biblatex` but I'm guessing you really meant `bibtex`). In either case: _don't do this_. Just take the time to add the information for the papers to your `.bib` file: the information needed is the same as if you hand-code `thebibliography`, and once you have it in `.bib` you can use it in different styles in the future. Not the case if you format by hand.

Comment: Is there something that's stopping you from opening one of the bib files and adding the missing entries "by hand", choosing their types (`@article`, `@book`, `@misc`, etc) and providing the fields (`author`, `title`, `year`, etc) as appropriate?

Comment: All the more so as there are excellent tools like `JabRef`that ease doing it without coding error.

Comment: @PaulGessler I just came back to this question because I wondered later if the point was that the stuff entered by hand was in `thebibliography` format....

Comment: thank you dear All, sorry for the delay, I put the two part of the settings I have , I have written the paper names in references section ,you can see the code in the edited post, JabRef looks interesting , I think I will write the .bib but JabRef is German based,too long written help

Comment: JabRef has an english documentation: http://jabref.sourceforge.net/documentation.php

Comment: @Johannes_B it's a bit vague for me, and I think I can not ask JabRef questions here right?

Comment: Your bib-file is a text file that you can open with texworks or texmaker. Jabref puts some magic glasses on your eyes and displays the contents a bit more comfotable (for some people). Depends on the Jabref Question, the community will decide if it is good here or not. Just try it. ;-)

Comment: Dear @Johannes_B now I created the .bib file from JabRef , but I could not find out how to refer my latex to read from this file

Comment: To be honest, it might help to read some basic literature.

Answer (score 1):

Google provide a service (scholar.google.com) which provide `BibTeX` information, it is not perfect, but improves with time.

- first look for the reference,
- then click the link `cite`
- ask for `BibTeX` format.

You can configure your account to give the `BibTeX` format as default.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: thank you but some of my papers don't have it